# How i can show only pdf,doc,docx format when click file upload

Tags: html, input

I am trying to block all extension except doc, docx and pdf by my code it's like accept for only `google chrome`

this is my code:

```
<input type="file" id="filedocxpdf" name="filedocxpdf" class="txtNotice" accept="application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help u!

**Javascript Solution**

```
var myfile="";

$('#button_id').click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#filedocxpdf').trigger('click');
});

$('#filedocxpdf').on( 'change', function() {
   myfile= $( this ).val();
   var ext = myfile.split('.').pop();
   if(ext=="pdf" || ext=="docx" || ext=="doc"){
       alert(ext); return true;

   } else{
       alert(ext); return false;
   }
});
```

**Alternate Solution 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkfile(sender) {
    var validExts = new Array(".docx", ".doc", ".pdf");
    var fileExt = sender.value;
    fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
    if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
      alert("Invalid file selected, valid files are of " +
               validExts.toString() + " types.");
      return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
</script>

<input type="file" id="filedocxpdf" onchange="checkfile(this);" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Other browsers ignore such an accept attribute, though e.g. 
Firefox for example, supports some simple cases like accept="image/gif".

You need to create a Javascript solution to check the file extension :

```
var file = document.getElementById('someId');

file.onchange = function(e){
    var ext = this.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
    switch(ext)
    {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'bmp':
        case 'png':
        case 'tif':
            alert('allowed');
            break;
        default:
            alert('not allowed');
            this.value='';
    }
};
```

example [Here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/7br93/1/)